# Calling a java method with parameter value set from dropdown select in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, javabeans

My task is to select a value in one dropdown, and with that value as a parameter, invoke a java method.

I tried setting a hidden input when via onChange, a javascript function is called, but could not use that value for passing as a parameter. (I have a bean, that has the method which i need to invoke from jsp after selecting value from dropdown)

Comment: JSP is a server side technology. javascript is a client side technology. Send an HTTP request that will be handled by a servlet, resolve the necessary bean and call the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make Ajax call to the servlet with XMLHttpRequest object in JavaScript.

You can make a successful call to servlet as:

```
<script>
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            var data = req.responseText;
            //HANDLE RESPONSE HERE;
        }
    }
    req.open('GET', 'servletName', true);
    req.send(null);
</script>
```

In servlet, handle the parameter passed from dropdown in request and accordingly, call java method and send response text as:

```
String responseData = "Output for your selection is : " + XXXX + "!";
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.getWriter().write(responseData);
```

Test crossbrowser compatibility before using it.